# Displaying alert message to user from spawner

Tags: javascript, python, flask, tornado, jupyterhub

We have written a custom spawner for JupyterHub to suit our use cases. In the same spawner, we have memory limits for every user, and this is checked within the `poll()` function, and logged on the server.

What I want to do is to display an alert to the client when he approaches, say about 90% of his memory limits, and another at 100%, displaying that the process is being killed.

Simply put : **I need to display an alert message on client browser window through the `poll()` function**

Is it even possible ? Can I do it using Flask ? (The resources I found online were about creating a new server. In this case, we already have a jupyterhub server running.)

**EDIT** : Here's my client side Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Client-side Javascript in the HTML

var targetContainer = document.getElementById("this-div");
var eventSource = new EventSource("/stream");
eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    targetContainer.innerHTML = e.data;
};

</script>
```

Here's the `poll()` function :

```
@gen.coroutine
def poll(self):
    """Poll the spawned process to see if it is still running.

    If the process is still running, we return None. If it is not running,
    we return the exit code of the process if we have access to it, or 0 otherwise.
    """

    self.log.debug("Polling " + self.user.name + "...")
    # peh = ProxyErrorHandler()
    # peh.get(503)
    self.stream()
```

And here's the `stream()` function:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route("/stream")
    def stream(self):
        def eventStream():
            while True:
                yield "Hello World"
        return Response(eventStream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

The Javascript throws a `404 Not Found` error, which makes sense because the poll() function runs every 30 seconds only.

Comment: The easiest way probably is implementing long polling in the browser side, preparing an endpoint in flask that returns the percentage, and having js display the alert if the percentage is higher than the threshold.

Comment: Thanks @LuisOrduz . I have been trying this. The problem is that the poll() function gets called every 30 sec for each user. 

Here's my poll():
self.stream()

Here's my stream:
app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route("/stream")
    def stream(self):
        def eventStream():
            while True:
                yield "Hello World"
        return Response(eventStream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")

Comment: I see, another possibility is using websockets, establishing a channel between the browser and the server, and sending a message to the socket when the `poll` function is run. On the JS side, you'd display the alert upon receiving the message.

Comment: I have tried websockets. Doesn't seem to work well in this case either. I have edited the question with more specific details. Thanks !